# MPVolumeView Route button error on second touch in IOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11, airplay, mpvolumeview

```
MPMediaControlsRemoteViewController Dismissing because view service terminated
```

I am getting this error in the simulator on iOS 11 when I touch the Route button (`MPVolumeView`).

The error doesn't appear in the debug log on the first touch, but does for each subsequent touch of the route button.

One of my TestFlight users says the Route button disappears.

I dont have any issues on iOS 10 and don't have an iOS 11 device other than the simulator to test on at the moment.

Called in `viewDidLoad()`

```
func addAirplayButton() {
    mpAirplayViewParentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    // Create subclass of mpVolumeView called SystemVolumeView which overrides func volumeSliderRect
    //let myAirplayView = SystemVolumeView(frame: mpAirplayViewParentView.bounds)
    let myAirplayView = MPVolumeView(frame: mpAirplayViewParentView.bounds)
    myAirplayView.showsRouteButton = true
    myAirplayView.showsVolumeSlider = false
    mpAirplayViewParentView.addSubview(myAirplayView)
}
```

I can't find any info on this error.

Comment: Are you having any actual problem with the app, or is this just one of those annoying messages that appears in the console? If the latter, then just move on. If the former, file a bug with Apple.

Comment: Yes, the `MPVoulmeView` route button is disappearing on the iOS 11 device.  I have started testing the new `AVRoutePickerView`.